# HTTP GET request authorization header is not set for some requests

Tags: c#, http, httpclient

I'm trying to use this code to send a GET HTTP request to some resource over https. The request must include the Authorization header with the Basic scheme in order to be authenticated:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    string credentials = "dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=";
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders
        .Accept
        .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    string jsonResponse = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

    return jsonResponse;
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I make the request for that url, I get a 401 Unauthorized response. Looking at the request with Fiddler shows that there is no Authorization header set on the request.

The authorization header gets through if I make the request towards a mock server such as [Request Bin](https://requestb.in/), for instance.

I thought that maybe there is a proxy server in between removing my authorization header for that particular resource I am asking. But making the "same" HTTP request using Postman from the same machine is successful.

Any ideas about what could be removing the Authorization header when making the request from C#? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the issue is with the cookie.  When a request is made to a server the HttpClient first looks for cookies before making the request and uses the cookie data to make the connection.  Using an IE I would delete in the history the cookies and then try capturing your application request using fiddler and see if the header is in the message.

Comment: @jdweng, thank you for your answer. But I am left with some questions... It is true that you can set cookies to HttpClient (using the WebRequestHandler object), but how does my HttpClient read the cookies stored by the browser (IE)?

Comment: The IE reads/writes the users temp space which contains IE Properties.  The same temp space is used by the Net library http client.  Microsoft defined the temp IE spaces as part of the windows specification.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what was the problem in the end.

Some servers respond with a 302 (redirect) when there is a missing slash at the end for instance, like it was in my case. Combining that with the fact that HTTPS strips out the Authorization header between 3xx requests, the second request to the server (with the slash) did not contain the Authorization header, hence the 401.